# Can't log in to Admin CP after updating from 2.6.1 to 2.7.3

Tags: debugging, updating

I've just finished updating my EE installation from 2.6.1 to 2.7.3 but now that the update is complete I cannot log in. I can access the login page but when I enter my credentials it tries to load http://mysite.com/admin.php?S=0&D=cp&C=login&M=authenticate but it just hangs there forever.

Some things I have tried based on similar issues I found on the EE forum:

- Tried using a different browser
- Tried clearing browser cache and deleting EE cache folder
- Tried adding `$config[‘admin_session_type’] = “c”` to config.php
- Tried adding `$assign_to_config[‘cookie_prefix’] = “site_name”` to index.php and admin.php
- Tried enabling debug mode in index.php and admin.php(did not get any errors when trying to load the Admin CP but when I try to load the homepage I am getting the following error:

  ```
  Fatal error: Class PT_Fieldtype contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (EE_Fieldtype::display_field) in \system_EE\expressionengine\third_party\pt_field_pack\pt_fieldtype.php on line 148
  ```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is pointing to an issue with [Pixel and Tonic's Field Pack](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/field-pack); you should attempt to upgrade it.

These "white screens of death" errors with the control panel after updating are frequently caused by an issue with an add-on; you temporarily disable them by adding  `$config['allow_extensions'] = "n";` to your config.php.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Apparently FieldPack replaced several other extensions and is now an all-in-one type deal. I deleted the old extensions and uploaded the new one via the link you posted as well as adding the line to disable add-ons to my config file. I am still having the same issue with admin.php but now on index.php I am getting this error since I deleted the old PT extensions:

    Unable to load requested field type file:  ft.pt_dropdown.php.

Confirm the fieldtype file is located in the expressionengine/third_party/ directory

Comment: Detailed update instructions are here: http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/fieldpack/installation.html

If that's not helpful, consider reaching out to P&T's support via twitter or email.

Comment: Ya, those are the instructions I followed, unfortunately I cannot follow them exactly since it requires access to the Admin CP which I do not have. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I love this answer (manually disabling extensions), as it coincides with a conversation my coworkers and I were having this morning about needing a "Safe Mode" login option for EE, wherein add-ons are disabled. We've run into numerous login issues with 2.7.3 that are all related to redirecting add-ons (see my answer below).

Comment: I am going to try going back to 2.6.1, installing the updated PT FieldPack extension, and then upgrade to 2.7.3, will report back.

Comment: Alright, that worked. Once I was back on 2.6.1 I updated to FieldPack 2.1.1 and removed the older versions of the FieldPack extensions. Then I updated back to 2.7.3 and everything is working fine now. Thanks again for getting me pointed in the right direction Nick!

Comment: Happy to help; happy new year!

Answer (score 2):

Another potential fix is to add the following config overrides:

```
$config['require_ip_for_login']     = 'n';
$config['require_ip_for_posting']   = 'n';
```

My team has had luck with that when dealing with add-ons that offer the option to redirect on login (Structure and Republic Analytics in our experience).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Mark, I will give this a shot if my current course of action does not work.